# PowerShell Az Analysis Services Merge-Partition -- getting credentials error

Tags: azure-powershell

We have a number of partitioned tables by month in Azure Analysis Services. The goal is for older months to be merged into annual partitions. In the past, Invoke-ASCmd was used with TMSQL to do this, but it was all hard coded, something that we very much want to avoid so that we don't have to manually maintain the process.

The only real documentation I found is the Microsoft page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/merge-partition?view=sqlserver-ps).

When I run the code below, I only get the model name back as a response and an error saying that the credentials are not correct. Is there something else I should be doing to make the Az function work?

Comment: Posted this before I was able to finish the question.

`[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$LocalCred
    $LocalCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $CredLoginName
    
    $Response = Merge-Partition -Name $PartitionDest -SourcePartitions $MySourcePartition -Database $MyDatabaseName -Cube $MyCubeName -MeasureGroup $MyTableName  -Credential $LocalCred`

Comment: I've tried it using the parameter `-Server $MyServerName` but then got the error that `This feature is not supported in AS Azure..Exception.Message`

Answer (score 1):

I used an older solution instead, using Azure-RM where I collected the XMLA from SQL Server Management Studio when the partition dialog allowed me to merge partitions and provided me the code used for that. I then created tokens and substituted the tokens for parameters to my Merge Partition function and then used the code below to run it:

```
$Command = ""
$TmslMerge = "
    {
        ||mergePartitions||: {
          ||target||: {
            ||database||: ||$LocalDatabaseName||,
            ||table||: ||$TableName||,
            ||partition||: ||$PartitionDest||
          },
          ||sources||: [
            ||$PartitionSource||
          ]
        }
    }
"
$QuoteReplace = "||"
$Quote = '"'

$Command = $TmslMerge.Replace( $QuoteReplace, $Quote )
Invoke-ASCmd -Server $LocalServerName  -Query $Command -Credential $LocalCred
```